# How to condense and call each function in a for loop or if statement under one larger function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css" />
        <link id="style_replace" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">.pretty { color:pink; }</style> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showApple(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#applepie_off, .apple_description").show();
            $("#applepie_on").hide();
        }

        function hideApple(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#applepie_off, .apple_description").hide();
            $("#applepie_on").show();
        }

        function showBanana(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#banana_off, .banana_description").show();
            $("#banana_on").hide();
        }

        function hideBanana(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#banana_off, .banana_description").hide();
            $("#banana_on").show();
        }

        function showCarrot(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#carrot_off, .carrot_description").show();
            $("#carrot_on").hide();
        }

        function hideCarrot(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#carrot_off, .carrot_description").hide();
            $("#carrot_on").show();
        }

        function showCookie(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#cookie_off, .cookie_description").show();
            $("#cookie_on").hide();
        }

        function hideCookie(bakedGood)
        {
            $("#cookie_off, .cookie_description").hide();
            $("#cookie_on").show();
        }

        function changeStyleSheet(styleName)
        {
            $("#style_replace").attr("href", "css/" + styleName + ".css");
        }

    $(function()
        {
            $(".contract, .apple_description, .banana_description, .carrot_description, .cookie_description").hide();

        });

</script>
```

Original   
        Larger Text

```
<h1>Recepie List</h1>

<div id="list">

    <div id="apple_pie" class="recepie">

        <h3>Apple Pie</h3>

        <a class="expand" id="applepie_on" href="#" onClick="showApple()">expand</a> 
        <a class="contract" href="#" id="applepie_off" onClick="hideApple()">contract</a>

        <img class="desert_img" src="images/apple_pie.jpg" />

        <p class="apple_description">   
            This was my grandmother's apple pie recipe. <br />
            I have never seen another one quite like it. <br />
            It will always be my favorite and has won me <br />
            several first place prizes in local competitions. <br />
            I hope it becomes one of your favorites as well!
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="banana_bread" class="recepie">

        <h3>Banana Bread</h3>

        <a class="expand" id="banana_on" href="#" onClick="showBanana('banana_bread')">expand</a> 
        <a class="contract" id="banana_off" href="#" onClick="hideBanana('banana_bread')">contract</a> 

        <img class="desert_img" src="images/banana_bread.jpg" />

        <p class="banana_description">  
            Why compromise the banana flavor? This banana <br />
            bread is moist and delicious with loads of <br />
            banana flavor! Friends and family love my recipe <br />
            and say it's by far the best! It's wonderful toasted!! Enjoy!
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="carrott_cake" class="recepie">

        <h3>Carrott Cake</h3>

        <a class="expand" id="carrot_on" href="#" onClick="showCarrot('carrot_cake')">expand</a> 
        <a class="contract" id="carrot_off" href="#" onClick="hideCarrot('carrot_cake')">contract</a> 

        <img class="desert_img" src="images/carrott_cake.jpg" />

        <p class="carrot_description">  
            Why compromise the banana flavor? This banana <br />
            bread is moist and delicious with loads of <br />
            banana flavor! Friends and family love my recipe <br />
            and say it's by far the best! It's wonderful toasted!! Enjoy!
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="holiday_cookies" class="recepie">

        <h3>Holiday Cookies</h3>

        <a class="expand" id="cookie_on" href="#" onClick="showCookie('holiday_cookies')">expand</a> 
        <a class="contract" id="cookie_off" href="#" onClick="hideCookie('holiday_cookies')">contract</a> 

        <img class="desert_img" src="images/holiday_cookies.jpg" />

        <p class="cookie_description">  
            This is an old family recipe that makes a very <br />
            delicious cookie.
        </p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You may want to look into jQuery.toggle();

Answer (score 1):

```
function showMyStuff(name,what) {
if(what) {
$("#"+name+"_off, ."+name+"_description").show();
$("#"+name+"_on").hide();
}
else {
$("#"+name+"_off, ."+name+"_description").hide();
$("#"+name+"_on").show();
}
}
```

usage:

```
showMyStuff("carrot",true) // this equals to the showCarrot();
showMyStuff("carrot",false) // this equals to the hideCarrot();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be greatly simplified

```
$(function() {
    $(".contract, [class$='_description']").hide();

    $("a[id$='_on']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(":not(img,h3)").add(this).toggle();
    });

    $("a[id$='_off']").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(":not(img,h3)").add(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

---

I used the **ends with** `[$='']` attribute selector, the **not selector** `:not()` selector, and the **add** `add()` traverser. Since you're using jQuery you don't have to inline bind your `onclick` events, use a click event binder.

The click event finds all of the siblings of the clicked element except `h3` and `img` tags and calls `toggle()` which shows it if it is hidden and hides it if it is shown.

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/SPtqW/

Answer (score 1):

[**See example of the following here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cm5RH/)

First, I've removed your `onclick` handlers from your HTML and placed them inside the jQuery instead.

Then in the click functions I've used the methods `next()`, `prev()` and `nextAll()` to help find the appropriate elements to show and hide.  See http://api.jquery.com/ for more information on these methods.

```
$('.expand').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.nextAll('p').first().show();
    $this.next('.contract').show();
    $this.hide();
});

$('.contract').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.nextAll('p').first().hide();
    $this.prev('.expand').show();
    $this.hide();
});
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/cm5RH/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to create an accordion style interface.  If so, you might want to take a look at the accordion widget that's a part of JQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to focus your changes on the "Description" and "Button", you can change the **@hunter's answer** with:

```
$(this).siblings(".expand, [class$='_description']").add(this).toggle();
```

And

```
$(this).siblings(".contract, [class$='_description']").add(this).toggle();
```

Here is a fork of @Hunter's Fiddle, with these modification : http://jsfiddle.net/akarun/FTRHQ/

Comment: WOW! Thank you sooo much everyone! I'll work on these and get back to you on how I end up putting it together!

Comment: I have to admit these were a little bit over my head... I ended u making two functions, one for show and one for hide:

Comment: function showId(bakedGood)
{
$("#" + bakedGood + " .description, .contract").show();
$("#" + bakedGood + " .expand").hide();
}
  
function hideId(bakedGood)
{
$("#" + bakedGood + " .description, .contract").hide();
$("#" + bakedGood + " .expand").show(); }
  
  function pretty()
   {
    $("h3").toggleClass("pretty");
   }